# Graphql: completely change field type in schema

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I need to completely change field type.

Situation: I have a gateway that combines multiple services. It fetches their schemas with introspection, transforms them by adding namespaces to types (with apollo graphql-tools) and putting them in nested queries (e.g. `Query: { ServiceName: { serviceQuery } }`) by building a new schema with `ServiceNameQuery` types and setting `delegate` resolvers. After that I need to create cross-service links.

I have `ServiceA` that has a type with property `related`, that contains ID from `TargetType` from `ServiceB`.  I need to change type of property `related` from `ID` to `TargetType` and add a resolver, that will fetch data from `ServiceB`.

Here is a real-life example:
[image]

To do that I run `visitSchema` (from `graphql-tools` transforms) over merged schema, find the field I need, fetch `TargetType` from schema and change the field type and set a resolver like this:

```
const targetType = schema.getType('TargetType');
field.type = targetType;
field.astNode.type = targetType.astNode;
field.resolve = (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
    console.log(parent);
    return null;
  };
```

When I run console.log the type over resulting schema before passing it to graphql server  — I see that It's type and astNode did change and they are proper.

When I run introspection — I see that type of field is proper.

But when I run a query like `query { ServiceA { serviceQuery { id related { id } } } }` I get error on request parse stage:

```
Error: Field "related" must not have a selection since type "ID" has no subfields.

GraphQL request (5:19)
4:       id
5:       related {
                     ^
6:         id

    at asErrorInstance (/.../node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:555:43)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

It event doesn't try to call `serviceQuery` resolver.

Where does it get the ID type of this field, when I changed the type definition? Where more I need to change it's type?

**UPD**
Even if I create new type like this:

```
schema = return visitSchema(schema, {
    [VisitSchemaKind.OBJECT_TYPE](type: GraphQLObjectType) {
      if (type.getFields().relatedNews) {
        // console.log(type.getFields());
        return new GraphQLObjectType({
          name: type.name,
          fields: {
            ...fromPairs(Object.values(type.getFields()).map(({name, type, args, resolve, description}) => [name, {type, args: {}, resolve, description}])),
            relatedNews: {
              type: schema.getType('NewsArticle'),
              resolve(obj) {
                console.log('foo');
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
      return type;
    },
  });
```

I keep getting this error and resolver is not triggered. If I in the same manner add a new field with different name — that works. But if name is the same — error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out. Stitched schema keeps track of underlying stitched schemas. Changing type at top-level schema doesn't affect it so leads to internal type conflict. So type should be changed BEFORE merging

Comment: how? can you provide an example please?